# Text parsed line by line with loop scanning grouped content

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

In a txt file, populations 0 and 1 each has its own parameter values, formatted like this:

```
population 0
gK 9
gNa 35
gL 0.1

population 1 
gK 9
gNa 35
gL 0.1
```

The file is loaded using ifstream, parsed using getline and stringstream.

I try making a loop such that when a line containing "population 0" is encountered, its parameters are read line by line according to the template "contents >> param_name >> param_val", 
parameter name is compared to an expected string, and its value goes into a corresponding pointer array (ie: population 0, gK=9 goes into gK[0])

Reaching the last expected parameter, or reaching next population (i+1), jumps to seek next population in the text (i+1).

```
void Parameters::Initialize(ifstream & pfile) {
 stringstream char_content;
 string temp;
 string line;
 string param_name;
 double param_val{ 0 };

 while (getline(pfile, line)) {

    stringstream contents(line);


    if (contents.rdbuf()->in_avail() == 0) { // if 
        continue;
    }

    if (!(contents >> param_name >> param_val)) { 
        printf("error reading line from file. position: file %s line %d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
        throw "error reading file";
    }


for (int i { 0 }; i <= 2; ++i) { 

        if ((param_name.compare("Population") == 0) && (param_val == i)) { //if condition satisfied, get subsequent lines up to next population

        if (param_name.compare("gK") == 0); gK[i] = param_val;
        if (param_name.compare("gNa") == 0); gNa[i] = param_val;
        if (param_name.compare("gL") == 0); gL[i] = param_val;

        if ((param_name.compare("Population") == 0) && (param_val == i + 1)) continue;
        }
    }
}
}

int main (){
    cin >> file; // .txt file
    std::ifstream paramFile(file);

    P.Initialize(paramFile);
}
```

Would appreciate if someone could help make a working version.

Comment: At my first glance: your sample input contains `population` (starting with lowercase). In your sample code, you compare with `"Population"` (starting with uppercase). Either, you have to edit your question, or if this is the same in your local project - this will not work as the `std::string::operator==()` is case sensitive.

Comment: Did you try to debug your code?

Comment: Hey Scheff, youre right, i changed that but still doesnt work.

Comment: for example breaking the debug at "if (param_name.compare("gK") == 0); gK[i] = param_val;" and adding a "cout << gK[i]" below, gives me 0 instead of the value in the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading `stringstream`, you have to continue reading the file to get the values for `gK`, etc.

Declare `param_val` as `int`. This way you can compare `param_val` to `int` counter.

Compare `param_name` with lower case `"population"`

`gK` etc. can be declared as `std::vector`, use the `push_back` method to add values to `vector`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

std::vector<double> gK, gNa, gL;

void Initialize(ifstream & pfile) 
{
    string line, param_name;
    int param_val;
    int counter = 0;
    while(getline(pfile, line)) 
    {
        stringstream contents(line);

        if(contents.rdbuf()->in_avail() == 0) 
            continue;

        if(contents >> param_name >> param_val)
        {
            if(param_name == "population" && param_val == counter)
            {
                double val;
                pfile >> line >> val;
                gK.push_back(val);
                if(line != "gK") cout << "error\n";

                pfile >> line >> val;
                gNa.push_back(val);
                if(line != "gNa") cout << "error\n";

                pfile >> line >> val;
                gL.push_back(val);
                if(line != "gL") cout << "error\n";

                counter++;
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
    {
        cout << "population " << i << "\n";
        cout << "gK " << gK[i] << "\n";
        cout << "gNa " << gNa[i] << "\n";
        cout << "gL " << gL[i] << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Barmak, I asked for a working version and you provided! Thank you :)